# A good introduction to axiomatic set theory

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I'm doing my undergraduate dissertation on axiomatic set theory, and i'm using Jean-Louis Krivine's book "Theorie des ensembles" as a reference book. My dissertation focuses only on the first two chapters " zermelo fraenkel set theory " and " cardinals and ordinals ". And i'm searhing for some references to help me write the introduction to my dissertation.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Suppes' [Axiomatic Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=skTCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) and Derek Goldrei, [Classic set theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=dlc0DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1), Chapman & Hall (1996)

Comment: I like Both Enderton's book _Set theory_ and Jech's book _Set theory 3rd millennium edition_. Have a look at them because maybe they are not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: For a historical treatment of the development of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, I would recommend ["The Philosophy Of Set Theory" by Mary Tiles](https://www.amazon.com/Philosophy-Set-Theory-Introduction-Mathematics/dp/0486435202)

Comment: You might find [this small note](http://karagila.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ests-wh.pdf) useful.

Comment: See [Textbooks on set theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251490).

Comment: @AsafKaragila This is not related to my question here but to an answer you gave here [link] (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916072/what-axioms-does-zf-have-exactly)

I hope i'm not violating any  terms by asking here, i just don't have reputation points enough to reply to your answer there.
There you gave your preffered list of axioms for zermelo fraenkel set theory which contained the axiom of regularity; but in Jean-Louis Krivine's book "Theorie des ensembles" he used the same set of axioms but excluding the axiom of regularity, so can we prove it from the other axioms?

Comment: No, we cannot prove Regularity from the other axioms of ZF.

Comment: @AsafKaragila humm i see, thanks for answering, i wonder then why it wasn't used in the book..